# Starling Quad Retangle Round Corners

Tags: starling-framework

How can draw a rectangle with round corners in starling using Quad? I'm not trying to add texture buttons to my sprite sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to make round corners in Quads. Make texture (draw bitmap or load it and make texture from it) and use sprite or image for that.

Comment: I wasn't trying to go that route, but I may not have a choice.